# PGP signature checks without keyring (using just the public key)?

Tags: python, c, perl, pgp

When you have the message and the public key the algorithm should be able to check it - but when I search for libraries that would do that, be it in Perl or Python, all I find is code that checks a message against a key from a keyring. What I want to write is a server side code - I don't want to use a file with the key ring there - because I want to store the keys in the database anyway and also I am not sure if the keyring code will cope with the number of keys I plan to store.

Are all libraries coupling the key store structure with the signature checking algorithm? If there are C libs for this - I guess I can try to make some Perl or Python bindings for them.